# Deep linking/Navigating to tabbed page in prism not working

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a master detail page as the root page for my application. As a detail page for that I have a tabbed page. In the tabbed page I have a content page and a navigation page containing one content page. In the master detail's OnNavigatedTo I'm retrieving some organisation data from the cloud and then I want to navigate to a manage organisation page which is the plain content page in the tabbed page.

Using NavigateAsync and a relative uri to the manage organisation page I find that the Tabbed Page OnNavigatedTo is hit twice and then I get an exception such as (simplified) below. I can also see Binding errors in my output showing that elements on my manage organisation page xaml tried to bind to the tabbed page view model.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the view model auto wire change in 6.2 or if it's a deep linking issue or if I've done something wrong.

```
"Sequence contains no elements".

at System.Linq.Enumerable.Last[TSource] (IEnumerable`1 source) [0x00079] 
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnAttachedToWindow () [0x00011]
in C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:189
```

Using XF 2.3.1.114, Prism.Forms 6.2, I'm not sure if other packages are relevant. If you think so I can include them.

Also interestingly, it works if I try navigate to the content page in the navigation page from the master detail i.e. "TabbedPage/NavigationPage/ContentPage".

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: There are a lot of moving pieces here and a complicated page structure.  It can be any number of things causing your issue.  Can you provide a small sample that reproduces the issue?  Also, make sure all your pages are registered for navigation. If you have a Page in your TabbedPage that isn't registered then it won't be able to find it.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Thanks for your reply. I created a sample here which replicates the issue at least on my machine. https://github.com/Troto/PrismJunkApp

Comment: I'm trying to work around it by navigating to a different page and then just tabbing back but it appears that the view model isn't wired up to the view. So there's not much I can do with that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first thing first, you don't have the proper XAML syntax for your TabbedPage.  When defining the default page for a NavigationPage in XAML you must supply the page via the Arguments element:

```
  <views:SimpleNavPage Title="Foo">
       <x:Arguments>
            <views:NestedContentPage />
       </x:Arguments>
  </views:SimpleNavPage>
```

You must also have the proper ctor in your navigation page:

```
    public SimpleNavPage(Page root) : base (root)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Now, I personally don't recommend navigating within the OnNavigatedTo unless you can absolutely guarantee that you will not be adding that page in another deep link, or navigation scenario.  Imagine you start out with NavigateAsync("MainPage") and that has an OnNavigatedTo that does a deep link navigation operation.  Now you decide to NavigateAsync("SomeOtherPage") in which it NavigateAsyc("AnotherPage/MainPage/SomeOtherPage/LastPage") from within it's OnNavigatedTo.  Now, you will have created an issue because the MainPage.OnNavigatedTO will have kicked off another navigation operation while you are still navigating to the next "SomeOtherPage".  You are asking for trouble.

Comment: It still isn't working. I made the fixes you suggested, thanks for that. But I'm still having the issue where the content page is binding to the wrong view model. It's using the tabbed page view model instead of it's own view model. This isn't using OnNavigatedTo either, this is using absolute navigation from app. I've updated my example repo to demo this.

Comment: Yes it is working, you just didn't add the `prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"` to the Page.

Comment: Interesting, I thought you made that automatic. I have removed it from every other page and they still work. That is working with that reinstated. Why is it needed in this case?

Comment: I did make it automatic.  Honestly, I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for this specific page automatically.  I'll have to look into it.  At least it will work if you explicitly add the attached property :)

Comment: OK sweet. I'm glad I hadn't just missed something haha. Thanks for your help!

Just looking back I accidentally made it explicit on the tabbed page because I was using the template pack. Maybe that one explicit one broke it?

Comment: Nah, that wouldn't have any effect on that.  The attached property is checked to see if it has already been added, if it isn't there then it is added automatically.  I really don't know why that view didn't work as expected.  When I debug and step through it works. Very strange indeed.

Comment: Brian, I just ran across the same issue where the BindingContext of a page within a TabbedPage was being set to the BindingContext of the TabbedPage. Once I added the AutowireViewModel attribute, it started working as expected.